# Finding other point's values on a line knowing one point and distance between two others

Tags: geometry, problem-solving

So I have a normal line that has points $A, B, C$ and $D$ on it (same order).
The distance between $A$ and $D$ is $392$.
Point $B$ is equal to $293$.
$$CD = 2AB = 4BC$$

Picture of the problem (drawn with my excellent paint skills):
[image: Picture of problem]
How could I find values of these points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\overline{BC}=x$, then you have $$\overline{AD} = \overline{AB}+\overline{BC}+\overline{CD} = 2x+x+4x=392$$
so by solving for $x$ you get $x = \frac{392}{7} = 56$. Then consequently
$$\begin{cases}
\overline{AB} = 2 \cdot x = 2 \cdot 56 = 112\\
\overline{BC} = x = 56\\
\overline{CD} = 4 \cdot x = 2 \cdot 56 = 224\\
\end{cases}$$
hence
$$\begin{cases}
A = D - 392 = 573 - 392 = 181\\
B = 293\\
C = B + \overline{BC} = 293 + 56 = 349\\
D = B + \overline{BC} + \overline{CD} = 293 + 56 + 224 = 573
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks! So $BC should be something like that:

392 = 2x + x + 4x = 7x
x = 392 / 7 = 56

Comment: yup! thats correct!

Comment: Marked as right answer! 7th grader right now and equations are a little new. However, I love math and we all actually use equations in everyday life. I've got some base with books & internet, I acquire things fast, ask for help (like just right now) etc, so it should be OK! :)

Comment: @John Doe wow! now start speaking some [$\LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a bit of [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) and you're fine!